# Como sair de um input por timeout em Python

Tags: python, input

estou fazendo um software em python rodando no raspberry, hoje ele possui uma entrada de dados por um teclado matrix (https://www.adafruit.com/product/419) e outra por um leitor de código de barras, que funciona como um teclado normal.

Fico em loop infinito no menu primeiro ouvindo as entradas do teclado matrix,
1 para entrada nele e 2 para entrada por código de barras.. o que preciso é o seguinte, quando entro no tipo 2 que é o leitor de código de barras, eu uso o input() do python, porém preciso de um timeout para quebrar esse input caso o usuário não passe nada no leitor.

Como fazer o timeout para sair de um input no python ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [signal.alarm](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) para implementar um timeout ou [select.select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select)

```
import sys, select
TIMEOUT = 10
i, o, e = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], TIMEOUT)
if i:
    print("Você digitou: ", sys.stdin.readline().strip())
else:
    print('Você não digitou nada :(')
```

Comment: Tovmeod, eu tentei utilizar o signal.alarm, porém ele não interrompia o input, ele apenas dizia que eu tinha digitado acima do timeout depois de eu apertar enter para sair do input..

agora o select, sempre que tento usar recebo o erro: io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Comment: no meu computador funcionou sem problemas, ubuntu com python 3.5. O que você usou?

Comment: consegui! precisei rodar como administrador dentro do LxTerminal do Raspberry.. no IDLE 2 ou IDLE 3 não funcionou..